# Finding gaps in column data

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen many questions asked about finding gaps in column data but haven't been able to transpose the answers to meet my needs. I'm an amateur as far as vba is concerned just to make my life challenging!

I have a column of number data in an Excel file. The column contains single and several consecutive blank cells. I need to locate the empty locations and use the Excel function to infill the gaps with data with linear series fill function. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

My code so far is

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long

lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row   'Search Column F, change as required.    

For Each cell In Range("F3:F" & lngLastRow) 'Starting cell is F3       
   If IsEmpty(Range("F3").Value) = True Then

  'store this row and check is next cell is blank & apply fill process      

   End If
Next cell
```

Comment: If you just want to grab the information from the cell above change your `If` block to .... `If IsEmpty(cell) Then cell.value = cell.offset(-1).Value` ... no need for an `End If` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this code will achieve a linear fill:

```
Sub LinearFill()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim startValue As Double
    Dim endValue As Double
    Dim thisRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row   'Search Column F, change as required.
        For thisRow = 3 to lngLastRow - 1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(thisRow, "F")) Then
                startValue = CDbl(.Cells(thisRow - 1, "F").Value)
                endRow = .Cells(thisRow, "F").End(xlDown).Row
                endValue = CDbl(.Cells(endRow, "F").Value)
                .Cells(thisRow, "F").Value = startValue + (endValue - startValue) / (endRow - thisRow + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just the job!